# How to turn List<T> into List<Map<K,V>> using Lambda in JAVA8

Tags: lambda, java-8

I want to get some Objects’ attributes which in a `List<Object>` and put them into a `List<Map<String,Object>>` using java8's lambda.In Java7 i would write in this way.To make this readable i want to translate it in another way by Java8's Lambda.

```
    List<HouseModel> _house = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>(2);
        for (HouseModel h : _house) {
            map.put("address", h.getAddress());
            map.put("number", h.getHouseNum());
            list.add(map);
        }
```

Comment: it can't be further simplified, because you are using independent keys here...

Comment: @Eugene well, in Java 9 it can be simplified using `Map.of()` (assuming you don't mind the `Map`s being immutable).

Comment: @Eran right, if only this would be tagged with java-9 :) still good suggestion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can map each `HouseModel` to a `Map<String,String>` and then collect to a `List`:

```
List<Map<String, String>> list =
    _house.stream()
          .map(h -> {Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>(); 
                     map.put("address", h.getAddress());
                     map.put("number", h.getHouseNum());
                     return map;
                    })
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or, if you are using Java 9 and don't mind the created `Map`s being immutable:

```
List<Map<String, String>> list =
    _house.stream()
          .map(h -> Map.of("address", h.getAddress(),"number", h.getHouseNum()))
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: IMO you should also suggest that what the OP already has in place in very good also, because of the way keys are chosen

Comment: @Eugene except of the bug of putting all the entries in the same HashMap instance.

Comment: it seems don't work .`Cannot infer type argument(s) for <R> map(Function<? super T,? extends R>`